# How to read Stock Names

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Is there maybe a table with descriptors that are sometimes added to stock names?

Examples:

- "AMAZON.COM INC. DL-,01" what does the DL-,01 stand for?
- "Alphabet-Cl.C" what does Cl.C stand for? The C stands for the voting class as far as I know
- "NokiaOYJ EO-,06"
- "Samsung EL.0,5GDRS"
- "ALIBABA GR.HLDG SP.ADR 1"
- etc.

Or are those even standardized?

Comment: Are these examples from a particular source?

Comment: If you pop these names into Yahoo Finance, it gives you the  symbols for these issues which trade on the various German stock exchanges.  I don't know what the suffixes on the stock name means but if you take a dive into the stock listings for the German  exchanges, you might find  an answer.

Comment: I basically just used the search bar in DEGIRO and wondered what those suffixes mean, but I don't think this is platform specific - it rather seems to have something to do with the stock market they are traded on. But I am unsure and before I make any stupid and costly mistakes...

Comment: Could DL-,01 mean Dividend Level (?) - 0,1% Europeans use the comma instead of a period in fractional percentages.

Answer (score 2):

[ADR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_depositary_receipt) is American Depository Receipts. If a non-US company was its shares traded in US Exchanges; it [or some institutions] buy the shares in primary market; keep this as collateral and create ADR and the ADR is traded in the US.

Like wise [GDR are Global Depository receipts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_depository_receipt) where stocks from one country are traded on other via GDR

DL is similarly a depository receipt trading in Germany.

Comment: In the case of Samsung: does the S in GDRS stand for short then? I heard that this sometimes happened to people that they bought shorts of the stock instead of the actual stock because it would only be a small suffix in the name?